# Create a table for each factor in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```r
>head(df)
                  Number          Label
1                      2            1-5
2                      2            1-5
3                      0            1-5
4                      2            1-5
5                      1           1-12
6                      0            1-1
```

I want to create a table for each label. So the end product is like this:

```
Label   Number   Frequency
1-5     2            3
1-5     0            1
1-12    1            1
1-1     0            1
```

Currently I can do this in multiple lines with base R, something like

```r
df2 <- df[df$Label=="1-1", ]
final.df <- as.data.frame(table(df2$Number))
```

I do this for each label iteratively. It's super inefficient. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be obtained easily with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
group_by(Label,Number) %>%
summarise(Frequency=n(),.groups='drop')
```

**output;**

```
  Label Number Frequency
  <fct>  <int>     <int>
1 1-1        0         1
2 1-12       1         1
3 1-5        0         1
4 1-5        2         3
```

Comment: what does .groups='drop' do? all the options don't seem to affect output. just curious.

Comment: you are welcome. if you don't pass the 'drop' argument, it would still stay a grouped dataframe. consider approving the answer if you find it satisfying enough.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Samet's method, you can also use count in dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(Label, Number, name="Frequency", sort=TRUE)
```

output:

```
 Label Number Frequency
  <chr>  <dbl>     <int>
1 1-5        2         3
2 1-1        0         1
3 1-12       1         1
4 1-5        0         1
```